# Cooking for the next day on yom tov

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, cooking-bishul

The Shulchan Aruch 503 writes that one cannot cook for the next day of yomtov . My question is once its the second night can one cook on the second night for the second day meal? Do we say the night is the same day or do we say the morning is a new day?

Comment: Why would we say the morning is a new day?  When do we ever say that?

Comment: With regards to cooking, why would one need to cook so in advance.  One might be required to cook close to the meal time. It may be a davar pashut that its permitted, but I have not seen anyone discuss it,that's why I asked

Comment: You're importing borer into ochel nefesh.  In borer you have to do it right before because that's not a melacha at all.  For ochel nefesh, cooking is still a melacha, you're just allowed to do it on Yom Tov.

Comment: I am not disagreeing, So I guess it's a real davar pashut that its fine,which I assumed,but never seen it spelled out,and the downvotes are worth it for clarification

Comment: What prohibition would it be? Hakhana?

Comment: That or the whole reason we allow cooking is because the food will taste better if made fresh, maybe night food isnt considered fresh enough, but like I said before its prob pashut that night and day is same,but no one spells it out

Comment: @Heshy my father (who never got to go to yeshiva) insists that this is the case despite my explaining that it's allowed.

Comment: @sam no one spells it out, because it's obvious.

Comment: Nothing in Judaism is obvious, but will agree that the halacha is its fine. Just wanted to see it mentioned somewhere

Comment: I would say that changing the question to what you said in the comment 2 hours ago, would make for a much better question

Answer (score 3):

You request an exlicit source (in the comments) that we say that regarding Yom Tov cooking that the day follows the night. (This is true for almost all Halachot, with the exception of Korbanot where the night follows the day.)

See the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן קיח - דיני הכנת הסדר](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0117_L2) in the middle of the 5th Halacha, where he says:

> וְעוֹשִׂין הַבֵּיצָה, בֵּין צְלוּיָה בֵּין מְבֻשֶּׁלֶת. וְצָרִיךְ לִצְלֹתָן וּלְבַשְּׁלָן מֵעֶרֶב יוֹם טוֹב בְּעוֹד יוֹם. וְאִם שָׁכַח אוֹ שֶׁהָיָה שַׁבָּת, יִצְלֶה וִיבַשֵּׁל אוֹתָם בַּלַּיְלָה, אֲבָל צָרִיךְ לְאָכְלָן בְּיוֹם טוֹב רִאשׁוֹן. וְכֵן בְּלֵיל שֵׁנִי, יִצְלֵם וִיבַשְּׁלֵם וְיֹאכְלֵם בְּיוֹם טוֹב שֵׁנִי, כִּי אֵין מְבַשְּׁלִין מִיּוֹם טוֹב לַחֲבֵרוֹ, וְלֹא מִיּוֹם טוֹב לְחֹל. וּלְפִי שֶׁאֵין אוֹכְלִין בָּשָֹר צָלִי בִּשְׁנֵי לֵילוֹת אֵלּוּ, עַל כֵּן צָרִיךְ לֶאֱכוֹל אֶת הַזְּרוֹעַ דַּוְקָא בַּיּוֹם.‏

The egg for the Seder plate should be prepared before Yom Tov.

If one forgot, then one may prepare it on Yom Tov, but one has to eat it on the morrow, otherwise it would be considered as preparing it for the 2nd day.

One cannot eat it that night, since we don't eat roasted food on Seder night.

On the 2nd night one once again has to prepare another egg for the Seder and then eat it on the morrow.

So you see, that **one may cook on Yom Tov at night for the next day**.